# Overwrite console.log across processes in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging

I work at a project that involves a medium sized app written exclusively in Node.js and I need to add logging without having to search and rewrite every console.log so we decided to **overwrite console.log**, warn, error to point to functions in the logging library (that is written by us, so we can tinker with it however we want) but the problem is **we can't make the override persist across processes** and this is very important to us because the files what will run on the separate processes will be written by users and we can't force them to require our logging library.

Comment: Within your own app, I'd suggest doing a refactoring anyway, to use the logging library explicitly instead of monkeypatching `console`. For the user code, you might be able to start the code through a wrapper that does the patching.

Comment: @robertklep thank you! I kinda wanted to avoid the wrapper approach since I hoped not to change too much of the internal structure of the app but I agree this is the better option and probably is better to take the time and do it accordingly